# how to read and update the SACL properties of a folder in a remote machine in active directory

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to read and update the SACL properties of a folder in a domain machine from the domain controller.
I came across this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/setting-access-rights-on-an-object) but I don't know how to use the `IADs::Get` to get the object of the folder from the active directory.
I am struggling to find the ldap query to get the folder, I searched all over the internet but I couldn't find a single example for this use case.
Can anyone help me with an example or a reference?

Comment: When you say "folder," are you referring to an organizational unit (OU)? Or are you talking about a folder on the file system of a computer?

Comment: I am speaking about a folder on the file system

Comment: Have you seen [Example Code for Setting an ACE on a Directory Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/example-code-for-setting-an-ace-on-a-directory-object#define-the-setright-function) in the same page?

Comment: Yes I also checked that example 
but in it they are passing the object to the function,
My question is how to get the object?
@YangXiaoPo-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IADs::Get` is only for objects in Active Directory itself. You can't use it for files on a file system.

To modify permissions a file on a remote computer, you treat it pretty much the same as a file on the local system. You can use [`GetNamedSecurityInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-getnamedsecurityinfoa), where `pObjectName` would be the path to the file in the format of `\\server\share\directory\file.txt` and [`ObjectType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/accctrl/ne-accctrl-se_object_type) is `SE_FILE_OBJECT`.

The credentials being used to run your program will need to already have rights to access that file on the remote system.

Some more reading here: [File Security and Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-security-and-access-rights)

Comment: Can I use the `GetNamedSecurityInfo` function that way even when I have not shared the file with anyone?
what is the share that you have mentioned in the file path?
@gabriel-luci

Comment: There has to be a file share of some sort. The administrative share might be enabled, which is usually the drive letter followed by `$`. For example, `\\computername\c$\directory\file.txt` The credentials you use to access it will need administrative rights on that computer.

Comment: If the file isn't shared in any way, then the only way to do it is to run the command on the computer itself. You can run commands remotely using [Remote PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands) or a tool like [`psexec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)